# GlusterFS or Ceph RBD for storing Virtual Machine image

Tags: kvm-virtualization, glusterfs, ceph, cloudstack

I am using glusterfs 5.3 for storing images of virtual machines in Cloudstack/KVM environment, majority of VMs are DB Servers (Sql Server & MariaDB). But I am facing performance issue on VMs specifically on database servers. I get lots of Time out even in small databases. Also I felt that the GUI of VMs and booting time is also quite slow as compared to VMs on local storage or NFS.
I have searched a lot for tuning but couldn't find any working solution, so please guide me whether I am missing any configuration parameter or I should go for ceph RBD or CLVM or any other solution for such workload?

Here is the brick information
Options Reconfigured:
cluster.choose-local: off
user.cifs: off
features.shard: on
cluster.shd-wait-qlength: 10000
cluster.shd-max-threads: 8
cluster.locking-scheme: granular
cluster.data-self-heal-algorithm: full
cluster.server-quorum-type: server
cluster.quorum-type: auto
cluster.eager-lock: enable
network.remote-dio: enable
performance.low-prio-threads: 32
performance.io-cache: off
performance.read-ahead: off
performance.quick-read: off
storage.owner-gid: 107
storage.owner-uid: 107
cluster.lookup-optimize: on
client.event-threads: 4
transport.address-family: inet
nfs.disable: on
performance.client-io-threads: on

Servers are connected to gluster node on a dedicated 10G interface.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer you are looking for.

Did you consider local storage + regular backups for databases?

I went this route of running databases over NFS storage and ZVOLs but they were dog slow and the added complexity of going over the wire always led to problems where you dont want them.

I then switched to local RAIDed SSDs for those database servers, and they run ever since like a champ with much better performance and no storage related issues whatsoever. Although this sounds rosy, if the local disks fail (which they eventually do), they need to be restored from backups - so make sure to do backups, watch whether they happen regularly, and check whether they are restorable.

Your database size may factor into this consideration as well.

Comment: Well as I also mentioned in my question that the VMs with local storage/NFS are running fine, but I need hyper convergence solution for my setup, maintaining backup is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go for Ceph/RBD with CloudStack, alot of users in the community use it with KVM + CloudStack.